# Finding the value of a constant given an equation where the sum of the roots is -3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, factoring, quadratics, quadratic-forms

I am to find the value of `h` given the equation `3hx^2 - 2x +5xh = 3`. 
The sum of the roots of the polynomial is -3.
I am having trouble finding the roots of the equation given the hindrance of `h`. 
How do I find the roots such that I may find the value of h?

Comment: Well, subtract $3$ from each side of the equation, and solve it you'd solve any other quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3hx^2-2x+5hx=3\implies$

$3hx^2+(5h-2)x-3=0\implies$

$x_{1,2}=\frac{2-5h\pm\sqrt{(5h-2)^2+4\cdot3h\cdot3}}{2\cdot3h}\implies$

$x_{1,2}=\frac{2-5h\pm\sqrt{25h^2+16h+4}}{6h}$

---

$x_1+x_2=-3\implies$

$\frac{2-5h+\sqrt{25h^2+16h+4}}{6h}+\frac{2-5h-\sqrt{25h^2+16h+4}}{6h}=-3\implies$

$\frac{2-5h+2-5h}{6h}=-3\implies$

$4-10h=-18h\implies$

$8h=-4\implies$

$h=-\frac{1}{2}\implies$

Comment: BTW, if you input $h=-\frac{1}{2}$, then you'll get $x_1=-2$ and $x_2=-1$ (the sum of which is $-3$).

Comment: isn't it that b^2 - 4ac yields 25h^2 + 12h + 4?

Comment: @JerYango: First of all, as you might have noticed, the $b^2-4ac$ term makes no difference with regards to the question at hand, because the $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ term is eliminated when you calculate $x_1+x_2$. Second (and as I also wrote it in the answer), $b^2-4ac=(5h-2)^2+4\cdot3h\cdot3=25h^2+4h+4$.

Comment: Yes it was irrelevant, although I did not get how you came up to 25h^2+4h+4

Comment: @JerYango: Simple math. $b^2=(5h-2)^2=25h^2-20h+4$, and $4ac=4\cdot3h\cdot(-3)$. Now calculate $b^2-4ac$.

Comment: it's 25h^2 + 16h + 4, that thing confused me really. Thank you anyhow.

Comment: @JerYango: Thanks, you're right. I guess I did not pay too much attention to it, because I knew that it was insignificant with regards to the final outcome. But it should nevertheless be fixed (which so I did).

Answer (score 0):

First rewrite your equation in standard form as follows:$$3hx^2-2x+5xh=3$$$$\therefore3hx^2+(5h-2)x-3=0$$Assuming $h\ne0$ we can divide it all by $3h$ to get:$$x^2+\frac{(5h-2)}{3h}x-\frac{1}{h}=0\tag{1}$$Now, if a quadratic equation has roots $r_1$ and $r_2$, then it can be written as:$$(x-r_1)(x-r_2)=0$$$$\therefore x^2-(r_1+r_2)x+r_1r_2=0\tag{2}$$You are told that the sum of the roots is $-3$. Therefore you know that:$$r_1+r_2=-3\tag{3}$$You should now be able to use equations (1), (2) and (3) to get your answer.